# How to identify pinouts in an Hp Server Front Panel

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, circuit-analysis, diodes, pinout

So I found some old server front panel and want to re-purpose its LEDs and buttons for some custom PC. How do I begin to identify the pin-outs without burning down the circuits?
[Image gallery](http://kompet3.tk/allegro/obrazy/galeria.php?roz=0&dir=fro_835_DL380_FrontPanel&img=100_3167.JPG)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is called 'reverse engineering'.

Comment: Things like the power switch, video and USB connectors are probably wired 1:1 to pins in the pigtail. An ohmmeter will help you identify the mapping. However, there appears to be a fair amount of active circuitry for all of the LEDs, so they are probably driven by some sort of I/O expander. This could be proprietary, or it might be something like I2C or SPI. Start by identifying the chips on the PCB.

Comment: There's also websites (heck, I have a mobile app on Android) that can tell you the pinout for each type of connector out there. EDIT: Also, check out any datasheets that HP could have on this product.

Comment: The pins on the left are for the VGA connector. You can tell from the Red/Green/Blue shielded cables with the ferrite on. The rest you would have to start probing.